# Display scroll bar in DropDownMenu in compose

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

I want to display a scroll bar in a dropdown menu containing many items.

It's mainly to give the user an idea that he can scroll for more items

Any ideas ?

```
DropdownMenu(
        properties = PopupProperties(focusable = false),
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .heightIn(max = maxHeightDropdownMenu)  ,
        expanded = true,
        onDismissRequest = {}
    ) {
        list.forEach {
            Item(
                name = it.name,
                clickable = Clickable(enabled = true) {
                    onItemClicked(it)
                }
            )
        }
    }
```